# Kivy access gridlayout within scrollview dynamically in python

Tags: python, kivy, scrollview

I am trying to add labels/buttons to a GridLayout within a Scrollview, but somehow I cannot access the GridLayout in python.
Consider the following .kv section

```
<DrvList>
    ScrollView:
        size_hint: (None, None)
        size: 0.95, 0.95
        GridLayout:
            minimum_height: self.height
            id: grid
            size_hint_y: None
            rows: 3
            cols: 1
```

and a simplified respective Python section

```
class DrvList(ScrollView):
    selection = StringProperty()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DrvList, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._src = ["C", "D", "E"]
        for x in self._src:
            self.grid.add_widget(ToggleButton(id=x, text=x))
        DrvList.selection = self._src[0]
```

I get an error

```
 AttributeError: 'DrvList' object has no attribute 'grid'
```

so how can I access the Grid? Also, any suggestions on making such a list "drag and droppable" such that I can move around items in the list with visual feedback? But most important for now the issue of how ti access the grid. self.ids.grid does not work, either...

EDIT: Kivy >= 1.11.x, so not 1.10 or below

Answer (score 1):

A few issues with your code. First is that the `ids` are created when the `kv` rules are applied, and I must admit that when those `ids` are actually available seems difficult to define. However, typically when `ids` are unavailable, that can be overcome by using `Clock.schedule_once()` like this:

```
class DrvList(ScrollView):
    selection = StringProperty()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DrvList, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.setup)

    def setup(self, dt):
        self._src = ["C", "D", "E"]
        for x in self._src:
            self.ids.grid.add_widget(ToggleButton(id=x, text=x))
        self.selection = self._src[0]   # Properties should be referenced using "self"
```

Also, note that in your `kv`, the lines:

```
    size_hint: (None, None)
    size: 0.95, 0.95
```

are setting the `ScrollView` size to less than 1 pixel by 1 pixel, so it will likely not be visible.

One other note is that your `kv` puts a `ScrollView` inside `DrvList`, but `DrvList` is a `ScrollView`, so you are placing a `ScrollView` inside a `ScrollView`, which may cause difficulties when you try to actually scroll.

Comment: Hi and thanks a lot for the elaboration. I just started with kivy and still have to get used to it. I was assuming when coding a class that I have to "repeat" the base class such as Scrollview here, but you are correct that then they become nested. I meanwhile dropped the kv file completely and in the classes __init__ method created a gridlayout. That seems to work fine and does not depend on the inner structure being created. Thanks for your comment about scheduling, that will help in general when setting up things!